# dictionary with different implementations; java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, implementation

so I have a project which is about a dictionary to show a list like a normal dictionary. The challenge is, we should use a couple implementations to show the words, like treeDictionary, HashMap and etc.

1. When I started the program, I have to choose what kind of implementation we want to use and then I choose the data.txt (in this data we have the german words for the first array and english words for the second one)
2. After the words showed on the JTextArea, I would like to have this option, that the user must not close the program and start it again to choose another implementation and the data etc.
3. But after I choosed the 2nd implementation, eclipse shows me an error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreExceptionat java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

4. It focuses on my ensureCapasity method.

This is my code:

```
{
     Component myFrame = null;
     static double startTime = 0;
     int data[], summeEntry ;
     static int size;
     static String[] deutsch = new String[16000];
     static String[] englisch = new String[16000];

     private void ensureCapacity(String o[],int newCapacity){
    if(newCapacity < size) {
        return;
    }
    String [] a = o;
    data = new int[newCapacity];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, data, 0, size);
     }   

    //open file
    public void read(File f) {
        LineNumberReader in = null;

        try {
            in = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] sf = line.split(" ");
                if (sf.length == 2) {
                    if(size >= deutsch.length){
                        ensureCapacity(deutsch, size*2);
                        ensureCapacity(englisch, size*2);
                    }
                    //kamusGUI
                    kamusGUI.dt.insert(sf[0], sf[1]);
                    deutsch[i] = sf[0];
                    englisch[i] = sf[1];
                    size++;
                    i++;
                } else if (sf.length == 3) { //I just copy from the first if. Then it can calculate the actually number of words
                    if(size >= deutsch.length){
                        ensureCapacity(deutsch, size*2);
                        ensureCapacity(englisch, size*2);
                    }
                    kamusGUI.dt.insert(sf[0], sf[1] + sf[2]);
                    deutsch[i] = sf[0];
                    englisch[i] = sf[1] + sf[2];
                    size++;
                    i++;
                } else if(sf.length >= 3){
                    //wenn ein deutsches Wort mehr als 2 Bedeutungen hat
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "Hallo, english more than 2 words");
                }
            }
            //to show your entries in output
            kamusSearchDelete.tOut.setText(kamusGUI.dt.toString());

            //to show how many entries you have from your dictionary
            kamusSearchDelete.stsEntry.setText("Total entr(y/ies): " + size + " words");
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("open canceled");
        }
    }

    public static void save(File f) {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(f);
            out.println(kamusGUI.dt.toString());
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("save canceled"); 

        }
    }
```

I have built already another JButton to call the main method (I can say, I try to reset the program through this button) and we can choose another implmentation. But it doesnt work properly. Maybe you guys have any idea,what i should do with the array? I am very thankful for every single advice or idea.

ive added the errors maybe you guys want to see it

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at aufgabe1.kamus.ensureCapacity(kamus.java:35)
at aufgabe1.kamus.read(kamus.java:50)
at aufgabe1.kamusMenu.actionPerformed(kamusMenu.java:156)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown    Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please add the exception with the full traceback into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are copying from one type of array which contains `String` references to `int` values.

```
String [] a = o;
data = new int[newCapacity];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, data, 0, size);
```

That is never going to work.

> what i should do with the array?

You either need to make the arrays the same type, or you have to convert/parse one type to the other.

I suspect the `String o[]` isn't used, and the `size` is not the capacity but the size used and what you really want it to resize the `data` as needed.

```
private void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity){
    if(minCapacity <= data.length)
        return;

    int[] newData = new int[minCapacity];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData , 0, size);
    data = newData;
 }
```

Comment: hello @peter now I have another issue to show the current total entries of the words. The number of total entries increases always if I choose another implementation. It needs just to show the current total. not the total from the old implementation + new implementation. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `System.arraycopy(a, 0, data, 0, size);`.

`a` is a `string array`, while `data` is `int array`. We can't copy string array to int array and hence the exception.